# Coloring Spatial polygons by Different Levels in R

Tags: r, spatial, r-sp

My main goal is to combine several spatial polygons into a map and then color them depend on the level of a variable.

To do that I first clean and aggregate the GADM data:

```
france <- getData("GADM", country = "FRA", level = 5)
```

Next, I merge few region as:

```
Normandie_names <- c("Basse-Normandie", "Haute-Normandie")
Normandie_index <- which(france$NAME_1 %in% Normandie_names) 
regionOfInterest_Normandie <- gUnionCascaded(france[Normandie_index, ])
Normandie        <- regionOfInterest_Normandie %>% geometry
Normandie        <- sapply(Normandie@polygons, slot, "area") %>% 
{which(. == max(.))} %>% Normandie[.]
Normandie$Name <- "Normandie"
```

2) second region in the same fashion:

```
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_names <- c("Bourgogne", "Franche-Comté")
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_index <- which(france$NAME_1 %in%     
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_names)
regionOfInterest_Bourgogne_Franche_Comte <-   

gUnionCascaded(france[Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_index, ])
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte<-regionOfInterest_Bourgogne_Franche_Comte%>% geometry
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte<- sapply(Bourgogne_Franche_Comte@polygons, slot,   "area") %>% 
{which(. == max(.))} %>% Bourgogne_Franche_Comte[.]
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte$Name <- "Bourgogne_Franche_Comte"
```

Now, I have 2 spatial polygons but I want to color them based on external values:
let's say that Bourgogne_Franche_Comte value is 100 and Normandie value is 30.
I want to color the map in the same color but with different level (i.e. dark or bright green).

First I thought to merge the two spatial polygons:

```
joined <- union(Normandie, Bourgogne_Franche_Comte)
```

then maybe use the plot function but

```
plot(joined, col = joined$Value)
```

The point is that in want to control the color and the level of the color - depend on the value.

thx for the help !!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. I understand that GADM is a widely used data set, but it would be great if you could make it easier for us to help you by either providing some ready made code to get data that is identical to what you are using, or creating a toy example with shapefiles created from scratch to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

## Your way, simplified

You can simplify the way you select regions while using `which` directly on the spatialpolygon object.
For instance:

```
Normandie_names <- c("Basse-Normandie", "Haute-Normandie")
Normandie <- france[which(france$NAME_1 %in% Normandie_names),]
```

You can use `rbind` to combine the two polygons:

```
joined <- rbind(Normandie, Bourgogne_Franche_Comte)
```

With `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, you can add your external data to your polygons. 
You can use a palette like `heat.colors` to color polygons according to your value.
Hence, the complete script would look like this:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Load data
france <- getData("GADM", country = "FRA", level = 5)

# Select features ---------------
# Select Normandie
Normandie_names <- c("Basse-Normandie", "Haute-Normandie")
Normandie <- france[which(france$NAME_1 %in% Normandie_names),]
Normandie.sp.tmp <- gUnaryUnion(Normandie)
# Add external data to Normandie
Normandie.sp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  Normandie.sp.tmp, 
  data = data.frame(region = "Normandie", value = 30))

# Select Bourgogne
Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_names <- c("Bourgogne", "Franche-Comté")
Bourgogne <- france[which(france$NAME_1 %in% Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_names),]
Bourgogne.sp.tmp <- gUnaryUnion(Bourgogne)
# Add external data to Bourgogne
Bourgogne.sp <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  Bourgogne.sp.tmp,
  data = data.frame(region = "Bourgogne_Franche_Comte", value = 100))

# Merge both polygons with their data
Regions.sp <- rbind(Normandie.sp, Bourgogne.sp)

plot(Regions.sp, col = rev(heat.colors(50))[Regions.sp$value/2])
```

## A cleaner way, which keeps complete france polygon

I would recommend to use `gUnaryUnion` with a vector specifying which polygons to merge only once. Then, you can add your external data.

```
# Create vector to define which regions will be united
Union.vector <- rep(0, length(france))
Union.vector[which(france$NAME_1 %in% Normandie_names)] <- 1
Union.vector[which(france$NAME_1 %in% Bourgogne_Franche_Comte_names)] <- 2

# Unite regions
Region.union.sp <- gUnaryUnion(france, id = Union.vector)

# Add external dataset
Region.union.sp.data <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
  Region.union.sp, 
  data = data.frame(
    value = c(0, 30, 100), 
    region = c("all", "Normandie", "Bourgogne_Franche_Comte")),
  match.ID = FALSE)

plot(Region.union.sp.data,
     col = rev(heat.colors(51))[1 + Region.union.sp.data$value/2])
```